# Как переместить текст в право и выше картинки слайдера, что бы при смене слайда он тоже менялся?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, frontend

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал сделать через absolute, да он смещается наверх, но только вот при таком же раскладе на других слайдах, текст друг на друге, что не круто. 
При попытке сделать его поверх всего слайдера, вроде все круто, но при смене слайда не меняется текст, как решить этот вопрос ?

```css
#slider { /*положение слайдера*/
    position: relative;
 text-align: center;
    top: 50px;
}

#slider{ /*центровка слайдера*/
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#slides article{ /*все изображения справа друг от доруга*/
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
}

#slides .image{ /*устанавливает общий размер блока с изображениями*/
 width: 500%;
 line-height: 0;
}

#overflow{ /*сркывает все, что находится за пределами этого блока*/
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

article img{ /*размер изображений слайдера*/
 width: 100%;
}

#desktop:checked ~ #slider{ /*размер всего слайдера*/
 max-width: 960px; /*максимальнная длинна*/
}

/*настройка переключения и положения для левой стрелки*/
/*если свич1-5 активны, то идет обращение к лейблу из блока с id контролс*/
#switch1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(5), 
#switch2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1),
#switch3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2),
#switch4:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3),
#switch5:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4){
 background: url('prev.png') no-repeat; /*заливка фона картинкой без повторений*/
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 0 -84px; /*сдвиг влево*/
 display: block;
 height: 68px;
 width: 68px;
}

/*настройка переключения и положения для правой стрелки*/
#switch1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2), 
#switch2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3),
#switch3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4),
#switch4:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(5),
#switch5:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1){
 background: url('next.png') no-repeat; /*заливка фона картинкой без повторений*/
 float: right;
 margin: 0 -84px 0 0; /*сдвиг вправо*/
 display: block;
 height: 68px;
 width: 68px;
}

label, a{ /*при наведении на стрелки или переключатели - курсор изменится*/
 cursor: pointer;
}

.all input{ /*скрывает стандартные инпуты (чекбоксы) на странице*/
 display: none;
}

/*позиция изображения при активации переключателя*/
#switch1:checked ~ #slides .image{
 margin-left: 0;
}

#switch2:checked ~ #slides .image{
 margin-left: -100%;
}

#switch3:checked ~ #slides .image{
 margin-left: -200%;
}

#switch4:checked ~ #slides .image{
 margin-left: -300%;
}

#switch5:checked ~ #slides .image{
 margin-left: -400%;
}

#controls{ /*положение блока всех управляющих элементов*/
 margin: -25% 0 0 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
}

#active label{ /*стиль отдельного переключателя*/
 border-radius: 10px; /*скругление углов*/
 display: inline-block; /*расположение в строку*/
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px;
 background: #bbb;
}

#active{ /*расположение блока с переключателями*/
 margin: 23% 0 0;
 text-align: center;
}

#active label:hover{ /*поведение чекбокса при наведении*/
 background: #76c8ff;
 border-color: #777 !important; /*выполнение в любом случае*/
}

/*цвет активного лейбла при активации чекбокса*/
#switch1:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(1),
#switch2:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(2),
#switch3:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(3),
#switch4:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(4),
#switch5:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(5){
 background: #18a3dd;
 border-color: #18a3dd !important;
}

#slides .image{ /*анимация пролистывания изображений*/
 transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
}

#controls label:hover{ /*прозрачность стрелок при наведении*/
 opacity: 0.6;
}

#controls label{ /*прозрачность стрелок при отводе курсора*/
 transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Слайдер на CSS</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="all">
  <input checked type="radio" name="respond" id="desktop">
   <article id="slider">
     <input checked type="radio" name="slider" id="switch1">
     <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch2">
     <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch3">
     <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch4">
     <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch5">
    <div id="slides">
     <div id="overflow">
      <div class="image">
       <article><h2>hui</h2><img src="1.jpg"></article>
       <article><img src="2.jpg"></article>
       <article><img src="3.jpg"></article>
       <article><img src="4.jpg"></article>
       <article><img src="5.jpg"></article>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="controls">
     <label for="switch1"></label>
     <label for="switch2"></label>
     <label for="switch3"></label>
     <label for="switch4"></label>
     <label for="switch5"></label>
    </div>
    <div id="active">
     <label for="switch1"></label>
     <label for="switch2"></label>
     <label for="switch3"></label>
     <label for="switch4"></label>
     <label for="switch5"></label>
    </div>
   </article>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Просто продублировать блок со слайдами и **получится то что вы задумали** !

*оффтоп* на [toster](https://toster.ru/q/435558?e=5409140#comment_1415226) я дал ответ , не ужели он не устроил ?

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50px;
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

#slides article {
  width: 600px;
  float: left;
}

#slides .image {
  width: 500%;
  line-height: 0;
}

#overflow {
  margin: auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article img {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}

#desktop:checked~#slider {
  max-width: 600px;
}

#switch1:checked~#controls label:nth-child(5),
#switch2:checked~#controls label:nth-child(1),
#switch3:checked~#controls label:nth-child(2),
#switch4:checked~#controls label:nth-child(3),
#switch5:checked~#controls label:nth-child(4) {
  background: url('prev.png') no-repeat;
  /*заливка фона картинкой без повторений*/
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 -84px;
  /*сдвиг влево*/
  display: block;
  height: 68px;
  width: 68px;
}

#switch1:checked~#controls label:nth-child(2),
#switch2:checked~#controls label:nth-child(3),
#switch3:checked~#controls label:nth-child(4),
#switch4:checked~#controls label:nth-child(5),
#switch5:checked~#controls label:nth-child(1) {
  background: url('next.png') no-repeat;
  /*заливка фона картинкой без повторений*/
  float: right;
  margin: 0 -84px 0 0;
  /*сдвиг вправо*/
  display: block;
  height: 68px;
  width: 68px;
}

label,
a {
  /*при наведении на стрелки или переключатели - курсор изменится*/
  cursor: pointer;
}

.all input {
  /*скрывает стандартные инпуты (чекбоксы) на странице*/
  display: none;
}

#switch1:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#switch2:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

#switch3:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

#switch4:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: -300%;
}

#switch5:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: -400%;
}

#controls {
  /*положение блока всех управляющих элементов*/
  margin: -25% 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

#active label {
  /*стиль отдельного переключателя*/
  border-radius: 10px;
  /*скругление углов*/
  display: inline-block;
  /*расположение в строку*/
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #bbb;
}

#active {
  /*расположение блока с переключателями*/
  margin: 23% 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#active label:hover {
  /*поведение чекбокса при наведении*/
  background: #76c8ff;
  border-color: #777 !important;
  /*выполнение в любом случае*/
}


/*цвет активного лейбла при активации чекбокса*/

#switch1:checked~#active label:nth-child(1),
#switch2:checked~#active label:nth-child(2),
#switch3:checked~#active label:nth-child(3),
#switch4:checked~#active label:nth-child(4),
#switch5:checked~#active label:nth-child(5) {
  background: #18a3dd;
  border-color: #18a3dd !important;
}

#slides .image {
  /*анимация пролистывания изображений*/
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
}

#controls label:hover {
  /*прозрачность стрелок при наведении*/
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#controls label {
  /*прозрачность стрелок при отводе курсора*/
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
}

.caption {
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  color: #999;
  position: relative;
}

.caption:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  border: 4px double #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
}

.caption article {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.caption article h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

#switch1:checked~.caption .image {
  margin-left: 0;
  transition: margin 1s linear;
}

#switch2:checked~.caption .image {
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 1s linear;
}

#switch3:checked~.caption .image {
  margin-left: -200%;
  transition: margin 1s linear;
}

#switch4:checked~.caption .image {
  margin-left: -300%;
  transition: margin 1s linear;
}

#switch5:checked~.caption .image {
  margin-left: -400%;
  transition: margin 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">

  <article id="slider">
    <input checked type="radio" name="slider" id="switch1">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch2">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch3">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch4">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch5">

    <div id="slides" class="caption">
      <div id="overflow">
        <div class="image">
          <article>
            <h2>DOUBLE CSS</h2>
          </article>
          <article>
            <h2>NOT JS</h2>
          </article>
          <article>
            <h2>NOT JQUERY</h2>
          </article>
          <article>
            <h2>PRACTICE</h2>
          </article>
          <article>
            <h2>ONLY CSS</h2>
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="slides">
      <div id="overflow">
        <div class="image">
          <article><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></article>
          <article><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></article>
          <article><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></article>
          <article><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></article>
          <article><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="controls">
      <label for="switch1"></label>
      <label for="switch2"></label>
      <label for="switch3"></label>
      <label for="switch4"></label>
      <label for="switch5"></label>
    </div>
    <div id="active">
      <label for="switch1"></label>
      <label for="switch2"></label>
      <label for="switch3"></label>
      <label for="switch4"></label>
      <label for="switch5"></label>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: и определитесь кто Вы такой или такая : Александра или Эрик

Answer (score 0):

используй отрицательные марджины (margin) для текста

попробуй так: codepen.io/anon/pen/VWpvmz я там ниже в ксс добавил стили, + класс .fff для слайдов с текстом

Comment: Постарайтесь дать более развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: куда еще более развернутый ответ? 
вот например
h2 {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

в таком случае текст будет привязан к блоку и будет меняться со слайдером, при этом выйдя за его пределы

Comment: @NagaSiren вот и добавьте ваш комментарий к ответу.

Comment: https://codepen.io/blodark/pen/PjpqrE     
Он исчезает при использовании отрицательных отступов

Comment: попробуй так: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWpvmz

я там ниже в ксс добавил стили, + класс fff для слайдов с текстом

Answer (score 0):

You have slides.Each of them has content(text, img ...).Your heading must be child(absolute) of your slide and must`ve top:-100%; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);

Comment: вы тут решили попрактиковаться в английском что ли? вышло не очень :)

Comment: да.решил. а что ?

Comment: на данном ресурсе вопросы и ответы публикуются на русском языке. практикуйтесь на основном сайте. Однако, вряд ли вам тут кто-то будет в грамматике ошибки исправлять, и если ваша цель повысить знания иностранных языков, то вряд ли это поможет вообще. Возможно следует выбрать другой сайт сети StackExchange: https://stackexchange.com/sites